# Whatever happened to Cissnei?

Tags: final-fantasy

In FF7: Crisis Core, a new female member of the Turks, preceding Elena, is introduced.  She's very close with Zack and makes it a point to disobey orders and allow him to escape numerous times.  When Tseng sends her to find Zack and Cloud to bring them back alive, before Shinra's infantry gets to them and kills them, that is the last time she's ever seen or heard from.  We know that Cissnei isn't her real name, but seeing as how she had such a major role, and wasn't added to the FF7 roster until the compilation stories, why is she never mentioned again?  What exactly happens to her?  Is she Elena from the original game?  I don't see how that's possible as she's much younger than Elena.  If not, is there anything that references what happened to her?